# Outer for loop begins from a certain position

Tags: java, for-loop

```
public void removeDups() {
    int i, k, j, lastFound = 0;
    if (this.nElements < 1) {
        System.out.println("Empty Array");

    } else {


        for (i = 0; i < this.nElements; i = lastFound) //outer loop
            {


            for (j = i + 1; j < this.nElements; j++) {

                 if (this.arr[i] == this.arr[j]) {
                    lastFound = i;

                    for (k = i; k < this.nElements; k++) {
                        this.arr[k] = this.arr[k + 1];


                    }
                    this.nElements--;

                    break;
                }
            }




        }
        for (i = 0; i < this.nElements; i++) {
            System.out.println(this.arr[i]);

        }




    }

}
```

the previous method removes duplicates from the object invoking it (Array),the problem is that i want the outer loop to begin from a certain position every increment, i assign the value of that position to the variable lastFound and put that variable in the incremental part of the loop but the program goes to infinite loop and never stops, what is the problem with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `i = lastFound` at every iteration. At the start of the outer loop, initialize `lastFound` to `i + 1`. That way it will increment normally if you don't reset `lastFound`.

Alternatively, get rid of `lastFound` and when you find a match, set `i = i - 1`, start the `k` loop at `i + 1` instead of `i`, and change the increment expression in the outer loop from `i = lastFound` to `i++`. I would also simplify your code by using `System.arraycopy`:

```
public void removeDups() {
    if (nElements < 1) {
        System.out.println("Empty Array");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < nElements; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nElements; j++) {
                 if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    System.arraycopy(arr, i + 1, arr, i, nElements - (i + 1));
                    nElements--;
                    i--;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < nElements; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of this: In first iteration,

```
   i = 0
```

now if this is false: `this.arr[i] == this.arr[j]` **then `lastfound` is never changed(remains 0)**, which will lead into infinite loop.

To fix the problem, handle the no match scenario.